# How do I set a nav li class to "active" using javascript in bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

EDIT: to be more clear, I am trying to make the navbar button active for whatever page you are on.

I've got myself a nice little navigation bar here and I'm attempting to make the ul/li class active when you're on each page on the navbar. However for some reason it's not working at all.

Here is my nav: (including the javascript I'm attempting to run)

```js
var selector, elems, makeActive;

selector = '.nav-link';

elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

makeActive = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        elems[i].classList.remove('active');
    
    this.classList.add('active');
};

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    elems[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
```

```html
<!-- Start Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-header" aria-controls="navbar-header">
        &#9776;
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A Trainers Best Friend</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="home.php">Home <span class="sr-only"></span> <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="clients.php">Clients <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Schedule <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Session Manager <i class="fa fa-handshake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav> 
<!-- End Navigation -->
```

As you can probably see my js is not working. I've tried changing up my selector to .nav, .nav-link, .nav li and nothing seems to be getting the job done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say "when you're on each page". Does that mean the navbar button is active for whatever page you are on, because triggering the function on `mousedown` won't do that.

Comment: Exactly right the nav bar button is active for whatever page I'm on. Doesn't mousedown trigger when you click a link? I am really new to Javascript. Sorry about that - maybe you could point me in the right direction? Also I will update my question to be more clear.

Comment: The `mousedown` event triggers when the user's mouse is down while over the specified element. It does not trigger when the user clicks a link.

Comment: To have the active button, you can just manually add the `active` class to the button for each page manually

Comment: Alternatively, you could parse the URL and add the active class dynamically to whichever button matches the URL

Comment: @Ginkoid adding the active class to each page manually isn't something I'd like to do as I am including my nav as a header for each page.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use this for all your pages. It parses the `innerHTML` of the buttons and finds a matching URL path from the dictionary.

```
const paths = {
    'About': '/about',
    'Help': '/help'
    // etc... for all your pages
}

for (let nav of document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')){
    if (paths[nav.innerHTML] === window.location.pathname)
        nav.classList.add('active')
}
```

You could also modify the code to query the nav link's `id` instead of the `innerHTML`. It will be a bit more work to add a different `id` to each link, but 
would hold up better if you want to translate your site at some point

Comment: Hi Ginkoid, thanks for the help. However for some reason this code does not work. I matched up all of my pages as you had specified but the active nav link doesnt trigger.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... I'm on the phone app right now... will test when I get home. For now, could you tell me what browser you are using?